# How To Add ShortCut Keys to JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, key-bindings

I am Stuck in some Step that I Can't Add a Shorcut Key like: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> to my program  , I am Searching for  one week and I could'd find any 
answers .

Comment: Read about key bindings: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll want to look at the [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for a good overview of Key Bindings.

Here's a quick example:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class KeyBindings extends Box{
    public KeyBindings(){
        super(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        final JTextPane textArea = new JTextPane();
        textArea.insertComponent(new JLabel("Text"));
        add(textArea);

        Action action = new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                textArea.setText("New Text");
            }};
         String keyStrokeAndKey = "control SPACE";
         KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyStrokeAndKey);
         textArea.getInputMap().put(keyStroke, keyStrokeAndKey);
         textArea.getActionMap().put(keyStrokeAndKey, action);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(new KeyBindings());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: guess What  !  It was Worked . 
Thanks For The Advice  and thanks for the solution 
it's the same for JTextField and i will look up keyBindings .