# Selecting more textfields with CTRL + A in Java

Tags: java, selection, textfield

I have more textfields in Java.When I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> I want all the textfields to get selected.
I tried this way, but only the textfield which has the focus gets selected.

Can you help me, please?

```
class Main{

public JTextField[] textFields;

private TextFieldSelected(int byteCount) {

    textFields = new JTextField[byteCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < textFields.length; i++) {
        textFields[i] = new JTextField(3);

    }

private class CtrlAAdapter extends KeyAdapter {

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        //JTextField textField = (JTextField) e.getComponent();

        if(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL == e.getKeyCode() && e.getModifiers() == 0)
            if(KeyEvent.VK_A == e.getKeyCode() && e.getModifiers() ==0)

                new SelectAllListener();}}


            //  for(int i=0; i < textFields.length; i++) textFields[i].selectAll();

         class SelectAllListener implements ActionListener {  

             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {  
                 for(int i=0; i < textFields.length; i++){
                     //JTextField field = textFields[i];
                    // String text=textFields[i].getText();
                    // textArea.append(text);
                     textFields[i].selectAll();  
                 }



         }
//      reset();
        //  e.consume();
         }
```

}

I change it, but still doesn`t work :

```
for (int i = 0; i < textFields.length; i++) {
         JTextField textField = textFields[i];
        textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(documentListener);
        KeyBindings keybindings = new KeyBindings(textField);


    }
```

class KeyBindings {

```
    public KeyBindings(JTextField textField){
        Action action = new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                for(int i=0;i < textFields.length; i++){
                    JTextField textField = textFields[i];


                    for(int j=0;j < textFields.length; j++){

                            textFields[j].selectAll();
                            textFields[j].transferFocus();
                            }
                }
            }
        };

        String keyStrokeAndKey = "control A";
        KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyStrokeAndKey);
        textField.getInputMap().put(keyStroke, keyStrokeAndKey);
        textField.getActionMap().put(keyStrokeAndKey, action);

    }
}
```

**and how can I make the unfocused fields display the selection too?**

Comment: The same question I asked before , Here is the answer click this link  
The same question I asked before , Here is the answer click [This Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13979667/how-to-add-shortcut-keys-to-jtextfield

Comment: I don`t undrestand what  your example does...

Answer (score 1):

`KeyListener` has a wonderful restriction. The component it is registered with must have focus and be focasable before it will receive key events

In order to receive this, you should use the [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) API

Basically, register a `KeyStroke` with the container containing the text fields, be sure to use `WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW`.  Walk the component list, looking for `JTextField` and call `selectAll` on the fields

The other problem you may have, is the unfocused fields may not display the selection

Comment: I tried in another way :  for (int i = 0; i < textFields.length; i++) {  JTextField textField = textFields[i];
textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(documentListener);
   textField.getActionMap().put("foo", new AbstractAction() {
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               for (int i = 0; i < textFields.length; i++) {JTextField tf = textFields[i];
    tf.selectAll();
                     
             }}});InputMap inputMap =textField.getInputMap();     inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK), "foo";}}

Comment: and how can I make the unfocused fields display the selection too?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is, use something like a JTextPane set to a single row, but this is going to require a DocuemntFilter to strip out new line characters